# How can a call a postgresql function from Django for live server?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, postgresql

### Here is my postgresql `function` in server.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.fn_wallet_statement(wallet text, s_date date, e_date date, p_table_name text, b_name text DEFAULT 'unknown'::text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

    declare 
        v_sql_bank              text :='';
        v_sql1                  text :='';
        v_sql2                  text :='';
        v_sql_tmp               text :='';
        v_sql2_v2               text :='';
        v_sql3                  text :='';
        ----------------------------------
        v_bank                  text:='';
        v_account_id            numeric;
        v_closed_date           date;
        v_closed_date_tmp       date;
        v_closed_balance        numeric;
        v_wallet                varchar(12) := wallet;
        v_start_date            timestamp := s_date;
        v_end_date              timestamp := e_date;
        v_table_name            text := p_table_name;
        v_excute_ind boolean;
        
      -- EXCEPTION
      v_error_msg text;
    begin
    v_excute_ind    := true;
    v_end_date      := v_end_date + interval '1 day';

    --***********************************TESTING*******************************************
    raise notice 'DONE 1';
    insert into test.test_user (username, wallet, current_balance) values ('user15', '01011991', 999999);
    raise notice 'DONE 2';
    --******************************************************************************
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_error_msg = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    END;
$function$
;
```

### Here is my python code in Django Portal.

```py
# POINTER
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def wallet_statement(request, submit_type):
    run_proc_query = '''select * from test.fn_wallet_statement('017XXXXXXXXX','2020-11-11','2021-03-12','test.wallet_statement_portal_017XXXXXXXXX_007','BANK');'''
    run_proc_cursor = connection.cursor()
    run_proc_cursor.execute(run_proc_query)
    result = run_proc_cursor.fetchall()
    run_proc_cursor.close()
```

> I am unable to call the postgresql function from django. I checked that the function is not calling. But normal select query from a table working fine.

> `Note`: the same query in the DBeaver (IDE) is working and calling the function perfectly.

Comment: when you say its not working ., do you get an error message?

Comment: I dont get any error message. but i checked that this function is not call from django. because in this function a set a insert query which should be executed if the function call

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.callproc("fn_wallet_statement", __arguments__)
```